# How do I dynamically pass a role name to IS_ROLE_IN_SESSION?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm setting up a masking policy that can be bypassed if the user's current role inherits from a specified role. This can be easily done with the function IS_ROLE_IN_SESSION. The challenge is I want to be able to change the specified role without having to modify the masking policy.

These examples assume the user is using a role other than ACCOUNTADMIN.

I got it to work with a session variable, but this is not secure since I can't control access to session variables:

```
create or replace table tab as select * from values('personal value') d (data);

set unmask_role = 'PUBLIC';
alter table tab modify column data unset masking policy;
create or replace masking policy hide as (d varchar) returns varchar -> 
    iff(is_role_in_session($unmask_role),d,replace(d,'personal value','hidden'));
alter table tab modify column data set masking policy hide;

set unmask_role = 'PUBLIC';
select * from tab;
-- Works as expected: shows personal value

set unmask_role = 'ACCOUNTADMIN';
select * from tab;
-- Works as expected: shows hidden
```

Ideally I would provide the role in a table since I can control access to the contents of a table but I can't get past these errors:

```
create or replace table unmask_role_tab as select 'PUBLIC' role;

alter table tab modify column data unset masking policy;
create or replace masking policy hide as (d varchar) returns varchar ->
    iff(is_role_in_session((select role from unmask_role_tab)),d,replace(d,'personal value','hidden'));
alter table tab modify column data set masking policy hide;

select * from tab;
-- Fails with error:
-- SQL compilation error: error line Check Arg at position 0 invalid argument for function [IS_ROLE_IN_SESSION] unexpected argument [(SELECT UNMASK_ROLE_TAB.ROLE AS "ROLE" FROM UNMASK_ROLE_TAB AS UNMASK_ROLE_TAB)] at position 0,

alter table tab modify column data unset masking policy;
create or replace masking policy hide as (d varchar) returns varchar ->
    (select iff(is_role_in_session(role),d,replace(d,'personal value','hidden')) from unmask_role_tab);
alter table tab modify column data set masking policy hide;

select * from tab;
-- Fails with error:
-- SQL compilation error: error line Check Arg at position 0 invalid argument for function [IS_ROLE_IN_SESSION] unexpected argument [UNMASK_ROLE_TAB.ROLE] at position 0,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an interesting question as it boils down to how to pass a "non-static" value to function that requires **string_literal**

> [IS_ROLE_IN_SESSION](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/is_role_in_session.html)
>
> ```
> is_role_in_session( '<string_literal>' )
> ```

---

Using view instead of table(if new entries has to be added then view defintion has to be updated, without changing masking policy definition):

```
create or replace table tab as select * from values('personal value') d (data);


CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW unmask_role_view
AS
SELECT 1 AS col WHERE IS_ROLE_IN_SESSION('PUBLIC')
-- UNION  SELECT 1 AS col WHERE IS_ROLE_IN_SESSION('...')  -- more entries
;

create or replace masking policy hide as (d varchar) returns varchar -> 
case when exists(SELECT 1 FROM unmask_role_view) then d
     else replace(d,'personal value','hidden')
end;

alter table tab modify column data set masking policy hide;

select * from tab;
```

---

A solution that requires defining all roles that should have access to data. It has one advantage though the roles are listed **explicitly**. One of the drawbacks is  maintenance of this table.

```
create or replace table tab as select * from values('personal value') d (data);
create or replace table unmask_role_tab as select 'PUBLIC' role;

-- here we compare against CURRENT_ROLE 
-- so we need all roles that have access to masked data
create or replace masking policy hide as (d varchar) returns varchar -> 
case when exists(SELECT 1 FROM unmask_role_tab u WHERE u.role = CURRENT_ROLE()) then d
     else replace(d,'personal value','hidden')
end;

alter table tab modify column data set masking policy hide;

select * from tab;
```

---

> [CREATE MASKING POLICY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-masking-policy.html)
>
> ```
> CREATE [ OR REPLACE ] MASKING POLICY [ IF NOT EXISTS ] <name> AS
> (VAL <data_type>) RETURNS <data_type> -> <expression_ON_VAL>
> ```
>
> You can use:
>
> - Conditional Expression Functions
> - Context Functions,
> - and UDFs to write the SQL expression.

Attempt 1: Standard call

```
SELECT IS_ROLE_IN_SESSION(u.role) FROM unmask_role_tab u;
-- SQL compilation error: error line Check Arg at position 0 invalid argument
-- for function [IS_ROLE_IN_SESSION] unexpected argument [U.ROLE] at position 0

SELECT IS_ROLE_IN_SESSION(u.role::STRING) FROM unmask_role_tab u;
-- SQL compilation error: error line Check Arg at position 0 invalid argument 
-- for function [IS_ROLE_IN_SESSION] unexpected argument [U.ROLE] at position 0
```

Attempt 2: Create UDF(executiing build SQL is not available)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION role_check(role_name STRING)
RETURNS boolean
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
   var res = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: 'SELECT IS_ROLE_IN_SESSION(:1)'
                                      , binds:[ROLE_NAME]}).execute()
   res.next();
   return res.getColumnValue(1); 
$$;

SELECT role_check(u.role) FROM unmask_role_tab u;
-- JavaScript execution error: Uncaught ReferenceError: 
-- snowflake is not defined in ROLE_CHECK
```

Attempt 3 SQL UDF(same error like with direct call

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION role_check(role_name STRING)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
   IS_ROLE_IN_SESSION(ROLE_NAME)
$$;

SELECT *, role_check(role) FROM unmask_role_tab;
-- SQL compilation error: error line Check Arg at position 0 invalid argument 
-- for function [IS_ROLE_IN_SESSION] unexpected argument [UNMASK_ROLE_TAB.ROLE]
```

Attempt 4 User-Defined stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE role_check_proc(role_name STRING)
RETURNS boolean
LANGUAGE JAVASCRIPT
AS
$$
   var res = snowflake.createStatement({sqlText: 'SELECT IS_ROLE_IN_SESSION(:1)'
                                       ,binds:[ROLE_NAME]}).execute()
   res.next();
   return res.getColumnValue(1); 
$$;

CALL role_check_proc((SELECT role FROM unmask_role_tab));
-- TRUE
-- Works only if table contains single entry
```

It returns result but stored procedure call cannot be used in masking policy/SQL query call.

Wrapping them with function will not work as it is not possible to call SP from function.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION role_check(role_name STRING)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
LANGUAGE SQL
AS $$
   CALL role_check_proc(ROLE_NAME::STRING)
$$;
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I ended up going with the explicit role list solution similar to what you have above.

Comment: @user14072884 Great to hear it. [As it was resolved I would suggest accepting it :)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)